# Connection refused SonarQube

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I'm having trouble trying to access localhost:9000 on my sonarqube server (172.16.36.68), it is running properly and I've configured it properly (I would think so at least).

The error I encounter is:

```
[admin@rockytm ~]$ curl -v http://172.16.36.68:9000
*   Trying 172.16.36.68:9000...
* connect to 172.16.36.68 port 9000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 172.16.36.68 port 9000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.16.36.68 port 9000: Connection refused
```

Same error is received when trying to curl by localhost:9000

The settings in /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties are as follow:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=[pass_for_sonar]
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.16.36.74:5432/sonardb
```

Where 172.16.36.74 is the server IP for postgresql and sonardb is the database in it.

```
[admin@rockytm ~]$ systemctl status sonar
● sonar.service - SonarQube service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; enabled; preset: disabl>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-10-13 10:27:40 CEST; 9s ago
    Process: 535908 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (c>
   Main PID: 535931 (java)
      Tasks: 58 (limit: 100268)
     Memory: 758.9M
        CPU: 20.067s
     CGroup: /system.slice/sonar.service
             ├─535931 java -Xms8m -Xmx32m --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.>
             └─535959 /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.8.0.7-2.el9.x86_64/bin/>

Oct 13 10:27:40 rockytm systemd[1]: Starting SonarQube service...
Oct 13 10:27:40 rockytm sonar.sh[535908]: /usr/bin/java
Oct 13 10:27:40 rockytm sonar.sh[535908]: Starting SonarQube...
Oct 13 10:27:40 rockytm sonar.sh[535908]: Started SonarQube.
Oct 13 10:27:40 rockytm systemd[1]: Started SonarQube service.
```

Postgresql-15-service running as well:

```
[root@rockydb admin]# systemctl status postgresql-15.service
● postgresql-15.service - PostgreSQL 15 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-15.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-10-13 10:21:24 CEST; 40min ago
       Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/static/
    Process: 13458 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgresql-15-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 13463 (postmaster)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 100268)
     Memory: 20.3M
        CPU: 2.320s
     CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql-15.service
             ├─13463 /usr/pgsql-15/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/15/data/
             ├─13465 "postgres: logger "
             ├─13466 "postgres: checkpointer "
             ├─13467 "postgres: background writer "
             ├─13469 "postgres: walwriter "
             ├─13470 "postgres: autovacuum launcher "
             └─13471 "postgres: logical replication launcher "

Oct 13 10:21:24 rockydb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 15 database server...
Oct 13 10:21:24 rockydb postmaster[13463]: 2023-10-13 10:21:24.450 CEST [13463] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Oct 13 10:21:24 rockydb postmaster[13463]: 2023-10-13 10:21:24.450 CEST [13463] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
Oct 13 10:21:24 rockydb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL 15 database server.
```

I tried adding firewalld rules to allow port 5432/tcp on the sonarqube machine as well as postgresql machine, maybe I need to add port 9000 on the postgresql machine?

Anyhow, here's the firewall-cmd --list-all:

Sonarqube server:

```
[root@rockydb admin]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 10250/tcp 22/tcp 1194/tcp 9000/tcp 5432/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Postgre-15 db-server:

```
[root@rockytm admin]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 10250/tcp 22/tcp 1194/tcp 9000/tcp 5432/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source address="172.16.36.68" port port="5432" protocol="tcp" accept
```

Here's also the pg_hba.conf file:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# host  all             all             172.16.36.68            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

**EDIT 1: I've made progress and successfully connect to the database:**

```
[root@rockytm admin]# curl -v 172.16.36.74:5432
*   Trying 172.16.36.74:5432...
* Connected to 172.16.36.74 (172.16.36.74) port 5432 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.16.36.74:5432
> User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

But so far I still can't access SonarQube by port 9000...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself, I added the IP of my SonarQube server in /var/lib/pgsql/[version]/data/pg_hba.conf and also fixed a memory issue regarding ELK.

This question is now closed.

Comment: Please provide more details on the memory issue and if it es relevant to the question

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime https://bigdata-etl.com/max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-max_map_count/